# Number of Lyndon words of 4 alphabets, One alphabet labeled, the other 3 unlabelled.

Tags: combinatorics, lyndon-words

1) In the following [OEIS Sequence](https://oeis.org/A029809), what is the meaning of One alphabet labeled, the other $3$ unlabeled?

The number of Lyndon words (aperiodic necklaces) with $4n$ beads of $4$ colors, $n$ beads of each color. One color labeled, the other $3$ unlabeled.

$1, 52, 5133, 656880, 97772875, 16032938340, 2812609211657, 518547356184000,\\ 99318297529004400, 19605670296090989500, 3966181169996511862429, 818782296743542722132528, \\171938262068874336023196923,...$

Number of Lyndon words (aperiodic necklaces) with $4n$ beads of 4 colors, $n$ beads of each color.

$1, 6, 312, 30798, 3941280, 586637250, 96197630040, 16875655269942, \\ 3111284137104000, 595909785174026400, 117634021776545937000, 23797087019979071174574,\\ 4912693780461256332795168, 1031629572413246016139181538, 219809927417367517614451764984,...$

2) The first sequence has more conditions, so the first sequence should be smaller than the second one, but the values seems the other way. Where am I making mistake?

Kindly explain me.

Thank you.

Comment: Asked also on MathOverflow: [Number of Lyndon words](https://mathoverflow.net/q/321619). I think that [this answer](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5085/moderator-supported-official-guidelines-for-legitimate-crossposting/5088#5088) gives a very reasonable advice on [meta-tag:cross-posting]. The most important suggestion is to link both posts to each other.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*Labelled* means that the combinatorial objects in question can be distinguished; *unlabelled* means that they cannot. So $A029809(n) = A074656(n) / 3!$ because A029809 combines Lyndon words of A074656 into equivalence classes under permutations of the three unlabelled colours.

---

> The first sequence has more conditions, so the first sequence should be smaller than the second one, but the values seems the other way. Where am I making mistake?

The first sequence *is* smaller than the second one. Perhaps the only mistake you made was not to look at the OFFSET field: [A029809](//oeis.org/A029809) begins 1, 52, 5133 **with offset 1**, whereas [A074656](//oeis.org/A074656) begins 1, 6, 312, 30798 **with offset 0**.

Comment: Thanks a lot. 

Comment: Please explain me this. 1234,1243,1324,1342,1423,1432 these are the six Lyndon words when n=1 in the unlabelled case. When we label the first alphabet the answer is one. Can you explain how this is one? if we cannot distinguish the alphabets then how to compare them in the lex oreder in order to check whether a word is Lyndon or not?

Comment: The number of Lyndon words (aperiodic necklaces) with 4n beads of 4 colors, n beads of each color. One color labeled, the other 3 unlabeled. is this equal to, The number of Lyndon words (aperiodic necklaces) with 4n beads of 2 colors, n beads of first color and the 3n beads of second?. I am still not getting hold of the word "labelled", kindly explain me with an example. Thanks a lot.

Comment: It's easier to explain via an example when n=2. If the labelled colour is A then the words AAAABCBCBCBCDDDD, AAAABDBDBDBDCCCC, AAAACBCBCBCBDDDD, AAAACDCDCDCDBBBB, AAAADBDBDBDBCCCC, AAAADCDCDCDCBBBB form one equivalence class. A is always A, but the unlabelled colours are interchangable, so you could call the four colours A, the first non-A, the second non-A, and the third non-A.